# Using a private image from Artifact Registry in CircleCI

Tags: docker, circleci, google-artifact-registry

I'm trying to set up CI/CD with CircleCI and I'd like the base image of my pipelines to be a custom made CI/CD image which lives in Artifact Registry. I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly authenticate CircleCI when pulling the base image for a job.

I've looked at both the [CirlceCI docs](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/private-images/) for authenticated pulls and the [Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#json-key) docs for authentication and I can't figure out how to put the two puzzle pieces together. It seems CircleCI requires some sort of password or access-key while Artifact Registry requires either glcoud for direct docker configuration (`gcloud auth configure-docker`) access token generation OR interactive docker logins (`cat KEY-FILE | docker login -u KEY-TYPE --password-stdin \ https://LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev`).

How can I use a private docker image in Artifact Registry as the base for a job in CircleCI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

1. make a service account json key from the Cloud console
2. make a project level secret called `GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENTIALS` in CircleCI with the key made in step 1
3. Put the following config in your CircleCI yaml file:

```
    docker:
      - image: us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/<PROJECT>/<REPOSITORY>/<IMAGE>
        auth:
          username: _json_key
          password: $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

If you base64 encode your service account key, use `_json_key_base64` as the username. Note that the password is the name of the secret we made in step 2.